# Show three products in cart popup - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, woocommerce

I need to show three products in cart page. Now when customer adds a product to cart there is a popup appears which contains current cart details. But what i need is, i need to show three optional products in that cart popup. If user added those product, then cart details should updated. Am using "WooCommerce WooCart Popup Lite" plugin for cart Popup.

Comment: what did you try to achieve it ? no one will write code for you until you start coding yourself, please write code for your solution and then ask here whats wrong with your code.

Comment: Did you try with mini-cart.php?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But doesn't work. This is a sample reference related to my ques. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033842/woocommerce-display-upsells-products-in-a-popup-on-category-page